# What is the best way to destructure big (nested) object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, destructuring

My goal is to destructure big (nested) object and assign it properties to variables, currently I have:

```
const { name, country, sunrise, sunset, timezone } =
   this.state.weather?.city || {};
    
const { temp, feels_like } =
   this.state.weather.list?.[0].main || {};
```

Is there any other option which can shorten/fit better this code?

Comment: There's no other way to destructure seperate keys in an object.

Answer (score 2):

#### Edit:

**Key concepts:**

1. Destructuring objects:

   ```js
   const data = { id: 1, name: "SO" }
   const { id, name, city = "N/A" } = data
   console.log(id, name, city);
   ```
2. Destructuring arrays:

   ```js
   const data = [ 1, 2 ]
   const [first, second, third = "N/A"] = data
   console.log(first, second, third)
   ```
3. Destructuring array of objects:

   ```js
   const data = [ {id: 1, name: "SO"} ]
   const [ { id, name, city = "N/A" }, second = {} ] = data
   console.log(id, name, city, second)
   ```

---

#### Original answer:

Here is how to do **Nested** object and array destructuring:

```js
// Input data
const that = {
  state: {
    weather: {
      city: {
        name: "new york",
        country: "usa",
        sunrise: "6 AM",
        sunset: "7 PM",
        timezone: "-4"
      },
      list: [{
        main: {
          temp: 10,
          feels_like: 14
        }
      }]
    }
  }
};

// Nested Destructuring
const {
  city: {
    name,
    country,
    sunrise,
    sunset,
    timezone
  },
  list: [{
    main: {
      temp,
      feels_like
    }
  }, second]
} = that.state.weather;

// Results
console.log(name, country, sunrise, sunset, timezone);
console.log(temp, feels_like);
```

With **default** values to **avoid** error - "can not read property of undefined":

```js
// Input data
const that = {
  state: {}
};

// Nested Destructuring
const {
  city: {
    name,
    country,
    sunrise,
    sunset,
    timezone
  } = {},
  list: [{
    main: {
      temp,
      feels_like
    } = {}
  } = {}, second] = []
} = that.state.weather ?? {};

// Results
console.log(name, country, sunrise, sunset, timezone);
console.log(temp, feels_like);
```